# Which heuristic for the simulated portfolio weights?

Tags: python, optimization, heuristic

I am trying to create a Simulated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier on 50 stocks, which you can find the [csv here](https://airtable.com/invite/l?inviteId=inv1OzctulKIXJvH4&inviteToken=f401f2229125cf0fb7cdf00857e5c3f9041d061d6e8285ec878fca279bb07ffe). Yet it already takes me several minutes to get a suboptimal solution: I can't draw an accurate efficient frontier:

[image]

Whereas it should be something like:

[image]

So basically, I want to create an efficient frontier of optimization of the weights $w_i$ of stocks in a portfolio of actions $i$ which returns are $x_i$.

I have imagined there is another way to get the weights in the following way. It should be easier to get that efficient frontier getting weights with given, fixed, portfolio standard deviations $\sigma_p$. Indeed, one can fix a grid of volatilities $σ_{p_1},...σ_{p_n}$, then for each $σ_{p_i}$, maximize expected returns with the constraint that the volatility is no larger than $σ_{p_i}$, to get $μ_{p_i}$. Then $(σ_{p_i},μ_{p_i})$ are $n$ points on the efficient frontier.

So, a first step would be to get the weights for one volatility $σ_{p}$. Knowing that for two assets, the portfolio variance $\sigma_p$ is

$$
\begin{align*}
\sigma_p &= \sqrt{w_1^2\sigma_1^2 + w_2^2\sigma_2^2 +2w_1w_2cov(x_1,x_2)}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Where $\forall i\neq p,\sigma_i$ are the standard deviations for a given asset.

We can maximize returns $r$ which are equals to the weights time the individual results for each action $RW$. This leads to the following optimization problem (I reduced it to two variables for the sake of simplicity):

$$\begin{cases}\max r\\
&\sigma_p \leq value\\
&\sigma_p = \sqrt{w_1^2\sigma_1^2+w_2^2\sigma^2+2w_1w_2cov_{1,2}}\\
&r = w_1r_1+w_2r_2\\
&\forall i, w_i\geq 0
\end{cases}$$

I don't know how to write it in matrix formulation:

$$\begin{cases}\max r\\
&\sigma_p \leq value\\
&\sigma_p = \sqrt{W^2\Sigma^2+2WW^TCOV}\\
&r = WR\\
&\forall i, w_i\geq 0
\end{cases}$$

Where COV is the covariance matrix between all assets.

But I don't know if it's right and how to write it in python.

## Context

My original approach was naive sampling. It doesn't work well because the efficient frontier is a very small subspace of the space I'm exploring:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import quandl
#import scipy.optimize as scoplt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
np.random.seed(777) 

def portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights ) *252
    std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
    return std, returns

def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate, df):
    results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios))
    weights_record = []
    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        weights = np.random.random(len(df.columns))
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        weights_record.append(weights)
        portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
    return results, weights_record

def display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate, df):
    results, weights = random_portfolios(num_portfolios,mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate, df)

    max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(results[2])
    sdp, rp = results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx]
    print("results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx]: ", results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx])
    max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[max_sharpe_idx],index=df.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
    max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T

    min_vol_idx = np.argmin(results[0])
    sdp_min, rp_min = results[0,min_vol_idx], results[1,min_vol_idx]
    min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[min_vol_idx],index=df.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
    min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T

    print("-"*80)
    print("Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp,2))
    print("\n")
    print(max_sharpe_allocation)
    print("-"*80)
    print("Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp_min,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp_min,2))
    print("\n")
    print(min_vol_allocation)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.scatter(results[0,:],results[1,:],c=results[2,:],cmap='YlGnBu', marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.scatter(sdp,rp,marker='*',color='r',s=500, label='Maximum Sharpe ratio')
    plt.scatter(sdp_min,rp_min,marker='*',color='g',s=500, label='Minimum volatility')
    plt.title('Simulated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier')
    plt.xlabel('annualised volatility')
    plt.ylabel('annualised returns')
    plt.legend(labelspacing=0.8)

    return max_sharpe_allocation, min_vol_allocation

returns = df.pct_change()
mean_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
num_portfolios = 750000
risk_free_rate = 0.0178

min_vol_al, max_sharpe_al = display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate, df)
```

As a side note, one should also notice that:

```
std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
```

Which leads to another equation which I don't know if it can be useful:

$$W^TCW = (\frac{\sigma_p}{\sqrt{252}})^2$$

## solving a linear system

The minimizer of a quadratic objective under linear constraints can be obtained by solving a linear system. Which is really easy to compute and not that hard to understand. To get the best sharpe ratio it gives the following:

```
def efficient_portfolios(returns, risk_free_rate, sigma, mu, e):
    weights_record = []
    volatilities = []
    results = np.zeros((3,len(returns)))
    i = 0
    for portfolio_return in returns:
        A = np.block([[2*sigma, mu, e], [mu.T, 0, 0], [e.T, 0, 0]])
        b = np.zeros(n+2)
        b[n] = portfolio_return
        b[n+1] = 1
        w = np.linalg.solve(A, b)[:n]
        weights_record.append(w)
        portfolio_std_dev = np.sqrt( w.T @ sigma @ w )
        volatilities.append(portfolio_std_dev)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
        i+=1
    return results, weights_record, volatilities

def display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, risk_free_rate, sigma, mu, e, df):
    results, weights, volatilities = efficient_portfolios(mean_returns,risk_free_rate, sigma, mu, e)
    max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(results[2])
    sdp, rp = results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx]
    max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[max_sharpe_idx],index=df.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
    max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T

    min_vol_idx = np.argmin(results[0])
    sdp_min, rp_min = results[0,min_vol_idx], results[1,min_vol_idx]
    min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[min_vol_idx],index=df.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
    min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T

    print("-"*80)
    print("Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp,2))
    print("\n")
    print(max_sharpe_allocation)
    print("-"*80)
    print("Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp_min,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp_min,2))
    print("\n")
    print(min_vol_allocation)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.scatter(results[0,:],results[1,:],c=results[2,:],cmap='YlGnBu', marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.scatter(sdp,rp,marker='*',color='r',s=500, label='Maximum Sharpe ratio')
    plt.scatter(sdp_min,rp_min,marker='*',color='g',s=500, label='Minimum volatility')
    plt.title('Simulated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier')
    plt.xlabel('annualised volatility')
    plt.ylabel('annualised returns')
    plt.legend(labelspacing=0.8)

    return max_sharpe_allocation, min_vol_allocation
```

And it gives the following plot and portfolios:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation

Annualised Return: 0.63
Annualised Volatility: 0.23


               DD  ADBE  ATVI   APD    NVS      A   ADI    AVB    AYI   AAN  \
allocation -19.33  0.03 -0.32  29.3  12.65 -14.57  2.85 -25.28 -13.17  2.77   

            ...   SWKS    NOV  KMT   MDT   RIO   PSA   STE  POWI  VALE   TX  
allocation  ... -15.61 -10.08 -7.2 -3.16  7.57 -9.39  7.93  5.13  1.07  8.4  

[1 rows x 51 columns]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation

Annualised Return: 0.03
Annualised Volatility: 0.13


             DD  ADBE  ATVI   APD   NVS     A   ADI   AVB   AYI   AAN  ...  \
allocation -0.6 -7.11  5.36  3.81  22.9 -3.69  7.37 -1.27 -1.13 -0.16  ...   

            SWKS   NOV   KMT   MDT   RIO    PSA   STE  POWI  VALE    TX  
allocation  -6.4 -0.25 -9.24  6.15  4.41  19.86 -1.31 -0.23 -2.99  6.05
```

[image]

Let me know if I did anything wrong.

But how would you do if we needed w to always be positive? I know that the solution cannot simply be obtained by solving a linear system. I would need to use a [quadratic optimization solver](https://scaron.info/blog/quadratic-programming-in-python.html).

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to sample the weights? Could you just optimize expected returns at fixed volatility to find the efficient frontier on a grid or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for your commnet @ChrisHaug. No other reason than it was the first one I thought of because it was convenient for graphic representation. At constant volatility, don't I risk having annual returns that could be lower than a higher constant volatility that I could have discovered by sample?

Comment: Here's what I mean: fix a grid of volatilities $\sigma_1,...\sigma_n$, then for each $\sigma_i$, maximize expected returns with the constraint that the volatility is no larger than $\sigma_i$, to get $\mu_i$. Then $(\sigma_i,\mu_i)$ are $n$ points on the efficient frontier. You could do the reverse instead (fix expected return and minimize volatility). Naive sampling doesn't work well because the efficient frontier is a very small subspace of the space you're exploring; you're unlikely to land on it accidentally and it would take a lot of samples to do so.

Comment: @ChrisHaug That sounds good! I tried to do that above but I have some issues to get the weights needed to get the returns (sorry, I'm not that much a statistician yet :) )

Comment: try editing weights = np.random.random(len(df.columns)) as follows: weights = np.random.random(len(mean_returns))

Comment: @HamithraJothiD Sure, but why would it change anything? As long as I have one column of returns per column in my dataframe it should be the same? I don't see how that's going to help me get that border more efficiently.

Comment: Would you be better off on one of the finance sites?